# Dynamically Splitting Rows in dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I need to take a CSV file and split the rows and have them cascade. The input CSV can have a varying amount of columns(always even), but will always be split the same way.  I decided to use Pandas because with some files the output will be 500,000 rows and I thought it would speed things up.

Input:

```
h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
```

Expected Output

```
h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6
A1  A2
A1  A2  A3  A4
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
B1  B2
B1  B2  B3  B4
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
```

I tried using the code below (cobbled together from some searching and my own edits) as you can see it is close, but not quite what I need.

```
importFile = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df_importFile = pd.DataFrame(importFile)

index_cols = ['h1']
cols = [c for c in df if c not in index_cols]

df2 = df.set_index(index_cols).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('Value')

df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series([v if i % len(cols) == n else ''
                        for i, v in enumerate(df2.Value)], name=col)
             for n, col in enumerate(cols)], axis=1).set_index(df2.index)


df2.to_csv('output.csv')
```

That gives the following

```
h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6
A1  A2
A1      A3
A1          A4
A1              A5
A1                  A6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# take number of columns and divide by 2
# this is the number of pairs
pairs = df.shape[1] // 2

# np.repeat takes the number of rows and returns an object to slice
# the dataframe array df.values... then slice... result should be 
# of length pairs * len(df)
a = df.values[np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[0]), pairs)]

# row values to condition with as column vector
dim0 = (np.arange(a.shape[0]) % (pairs))[:, None ]

# column values to condition with as row vector
dim1 = np.repeat(np.arange(pairs), 2)

# boolean mask to use in np.where generated
# via the magic of numpy broadcasting
mask = dim0 >= dim1

# QED
pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, a, ''), columns=df.columns)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but only hits the first two rows. It needs to roll through every row in the input file.

Comment: @mrh5028 unpdated

Comment: Worked perfectly! Now to work on understanding exactly what is going on.

Comment: @mrh5028 added comments... apologies for the laziniess.

Comment: Didn't need to do that, I was going to try on my own. But thanks! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dfNew = pd.DataFrame()
ct = 1
while ct <= df.shape[1]/2 :
    dfNew = dfNew.append(df[df.columns[:2*ct]])
    ct +=1

dfNew.sort_values(['h1'], ascending=[True]).reset_index(drop=True).fillna("")
print df

   h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6
0  A1  A2                
1  A1  A2  A3  A4        
2  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
3  B1  B2                
4  B1  B2  B3  B4        
5  B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
```